# Tkinter: adding label changes height of its frame

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am playing with Tkinter adding frames and labels to those frames.  Please, find the code below:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Example of Tkinter module')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800,600))

frame_top    = Frame(root, width=800, height=120, bg="#154e72")
frame_left   = Frame(root, width=240, height=420, bg="#154e72")
frame_right  = Frame(root, width=550, height=420, bg="#9dc8e3")
frame_bottom = Frame(root, width=800, height=50,  bg="#154e72")

root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

frame_top.grid  (row=0,sticky="ew")
frame_left.grid (row=1,sticky="w")
frame_right.grid(row=1,sticky="e")
frame_bottom.grid(row=2,sticky="ew")

label_1 = Label(frame_top, text="text label",bg="#154e72")

frame_top.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
frame_top.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

#label_1.grid(sticky="w")

root.mainloop()
```

If the code is run with the label_1.grid(sticky="w") line commented, the result is:

[image: Frameset with proper width of top frame]

If I try to display the label, things change like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Python version 2.7.11. I also tried to pack it, with the same result.

EDIT:

Seams like I posted before thinking it through, and I basically omitted the real question. Here it goes:

How can I place the label in the **frame_top** and keep the frame height around 120px?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @ParvizKarimli want the top frame to stay 120px high even with the label on it.

Comment: Do you get what you need with `label_1.grid(sticky="w")`?

Comment: No, it changes the height of the top frame.

Comment: Do you know what `sticky` does at all?

Comment: why do you need the top to be exactly 120 pixels high? tkinter works much better when you let it decide how tall an area should be based on what's in that area. Also, shouldn't the title be "... changes the *height* of a frame"?

Comment: @BryanOakley of course you are right, it should be height, my mistake. I suppose you are right. Maybe I am not using Tkinter the correct way. Thank you.

Comment: The sizes are too big. The question is not clear enough for me yet that what you want to get. Like why do you want it to be exactly 120? It's too big for a `height`. And if you don't use `sticky`, it will of course get slid out of the screen.

Comment: I want a 120px high frame with one simple label on top of it.

Comment: I got the question. @ERIK_SON, so basically, the position of `frame_top` is top (`row=0`), and the height of this frame starts from that point to up, so we cannot see its height, doesn't matter if it's 120 or less (20) or more (220), it will look visually same -- it just won't show up the whole tall of the frame, because it will get out of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is due to tkinter's "shrink to fit" behavior. When you add a label to the top frame, the top frame will resize itself to be just tall enough to fit its contents. You can get the exact same visual behavior if you remove the label but set the height of the top frame to 25.

When the top frame is reset to a smaller height, all of the extra space is allocated to row 1 (as per your weight options). Because of how you placed the frames in row 1 and because they aren't tall enough to fill the space, and because they don't stick to the top or bottom of the space, they appear to float in the middle of row 1.

---

If your main goal is to simply have a centered label (based on comments to this answer), you can just add some padding to the label when you use `pack` or `grid`. Your other choice is to use `place` which doesn't have the "shrink to fit" behavior.

Here's a solution using `pack`, for the case where you really don't care about the exact height of the area, and only care for a little vertical padding:

```
label_1.pack(side="top", pady=50)
```

If your requirement truly is to have an exactly 120 pixel tall top region, and you need a label centered in that area, `place` is a good choice because it allows for relative placement:

```
label_1.place(relx=.5, rely=.5)
```

Comment: OK, is there a way to keep the height 120 with the label on? Ideally I would like the label to be centered vertically in the left half of top frame. Is that possible with Tkinter?

Comment: There are many ways. You can force the label to be that height, you can using padding, or you can turn geometry propagation off. Why does the top have to be exactly 120 pixels tall? What's magical about 120? Why not just add some padding to the label, and let tkinter figure out the height based on the current font?

Comment: @ERIK_SON: if you want the label centered, and you don't care if the top is 120 or 100 or 130, but you do want a little space around the label, my recommendation is to do something like `label_1.pack(side="top", pady=50)`

Comment: If you kindly add that last comment to the answer I'll accept is as valid. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ERIK_SON: Your question asked "why did the height change?", not "how do I center a label?". I'll add the information you asked for, but make sure when you ask a question you're really asking about the problem you are trying to solve and not about something else.

Comment: You are right, the question is not stated correctly. I will edit it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the height of frame_top equal to 120 by taking in consideration the following notes:

- The height of `root` is 600 but the sum of heights of other frames is 420 + 120 + 50 = 590
- The width of `root` is 800 whereas the sum of widths of the left and right frames is 550 + 240 = 790

Now you need to make the following adjustments:

1. You can thus add two horizontal frames of `width=5` for each. One below `frame_top` and the other above `frame_bottom`.
2. You can create one last frame which occupies the 10 pixels width that separate `frame_left` and `frame_right`.
3. You must use `columnspan` option for `frame_top` and `frame_buttom`
   Do not forget to specify the column number for the rest of the frames.
4. After this logic building and adjustments are done, you must apply [`grid_propagate()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method) method on `frame_top`.

## Full program:

Here is the full solution putting together the elements I mentioned above:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Example of Tkinter module')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800,600))

frame_top    = Frame(root, width=800, height=120, bg="#154e72")
frame_left   = Frame(root, width=240, height=420, bg="#154e72")
frame_right  = Frame(root, width=550, height=420, bg="#9dc8e3")
frame_bottom = Frame(root, width=800, height=50,  bg="#154e72")

horizontal_frame_1 = Frame(root, width=800, height=5)
horizontal_frame_1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')

root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

frame_top.grid  (row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")

vertical_frame = Frame(root, width=10, height=420)
vertical_frame.grid(row=2, column=1)
frame_left.grid (row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
frame_right.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="e")



horizontal_frame_2 = Frame(root, width=800, height=5)
horizontal_frame_2.grid(row=3, columnspan=3)

frame_bottom.grid(row=4, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")

label_1 = Label(frame_top, text="text label",bg="#154e72")

label_1.grid(sticky="w")
frame_top.grid_propagate(0)

root.mainloop()
```

## Demo

This is what you have been looking for:

[image]